# Rust ownership restriction workaround

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, borrow-checker, ownership

I get this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `updated_setting_values`
  --> swu3\src\data_processor\mod.rs:53:9
   |
37 |         let updated_setting_values = data_management(
   |             ----------------------- move occurs because `updated_setting_values` has type `Vec<interfaces::inputs::constants::constants::SettingValues>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
52 |         self.all_setting_values_in_memory = updated_setting_values;
   |                                            ----------------------- value moved here
53 |         updated_setting_values
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

```rust
pub struct DataProcessor {
    count_iterations: u8,
    all_setting_values_in_memory: Vec<SettingValues>,
}

impl DataProcessor {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            count_iterations: 0,
            all_setting_values_in_memory: vec![SettingValues::new()],
        }
    }

    pub fn process_step(
        &mut self,
        default_settings: &[DefaultSetting],
        mode_specific_values: &Vec<SettingValue>,
        current_mode: Mode,
        current_profile: ProfileId,
        reset_mode_flag: bool,
        profile_update_status: ProfileUpdate,
        stored_setting_values: &Vec<SettingValues>,
    ) -> Vec<SettingValues> {
        let is_initial_run = self.count_iterations < 3;

        let selected_values = if INTERNAL_MEMORY_SWITCH {
            &self.all_setting_values_in_memory
        } else {
            stored_setting_values
        };

        let updated_setting_values = data_management(
            default_settings,
            selected_values,
            mode_specific_values,
            current_mode,
            current_profile,
            is_initial_run,
            reset_mode_flag,
            profile_update_status
        );

        if self.count_iterations <= 3 {
            self.count_iterations += 1;
        }

        self.all_setting_values_in_memory = updated_setting_values;
        updated_setting_values
    }
}
```

In this code, `self.all_setting_values_in_memory` should hold the value of `updated_setting_values`, that the output of the function `data_management`. I understand that `self.all_setting_values_in_memory` takes ownership of `set_setting_values_all_modes_all_profiles`, but I cannot find a simple way to return `set_setting_values_all_modes_all_profiles` from `process_step`. I should also avoid to use clone because we have memory constraint.
I would be really thankful if anyone has a simple workaround idea for this.

Comment: Consider changing the signature of `process_step` such that it returns a borrowed slice `&[SettingValues]` instead of an owned `Vec`, and then return a borrow of `&self.all_setting_values_in_memory` after the assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve here. The question could use some improved formatting, brevity and clearness. However the solution to your problem might be to return `&self.all_setting_values_in_memory` and change the return type to `&[SettingValues]`